# Focus listener in android tabs

Tags: android

I am using tabs swipe in my activity the problem I have a hardware keyboard for my mobile when I tried to enter data into edit text it is not taking input so I used onTouchListener() to re enable focus for the edit text it is working fine but user have to touch each and every edit text at least once this is my problem is there any way to over come this problem so hat focus listener work properly like in activity's

I tried with

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState); edit_mobilenor.postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub edit_mobilenor.requestFocusFromTouch(); } }, 400); 
}also but no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling extensively ,I got to know that the bug is : TabHost registers an OnTouchModeChangeListener in onAttachedToWindow() that steals focus when leaving touch mode.

So to regain focus for that edit text there are 2 ways

```
1)you can use onTouchListener which will re produce focus for edit text like  this
 editText.onTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.requestFocusFromTouch();
    return false;
    }
}

2)you can remove the OnTouchModeChangeListener in onAttachedToWindow() using the following code

mTabHost.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {}

        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
                  mTabHost.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnTouchModeChangeListener(mTabHost);
        }
    });
```

For this question answer is 2 one

Answer (score 0):

Use IME option in Editext

Check this link

http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/using-edit-text-ime-option-in-android-app/

Comment: **your answer is not working for me because I have a 10 edit text's in a tab swappable when ever screen loads focus should be in first edit text after user entering 10 digits in edit text focus should change to next edit text this functionality I need for all 10 edit text's**@kumar

Comment: for this use TextChangeListner on EditText..Count the characters you enter in edittext and once the count reaches 10 change the focus to next editText

Comment: yes I already tried with TextChangeListner but it is not working in tabs